# Bind just an object or class to grid view in devexpress

Tags: c#, gridview, binding, devexpress, datasource

I have a gridview in devexpress c#.when i want to bind a list to its datasource it works fine as you can see :

```
    gridControl.DataSource = new BindingList<ViewJoint>(_jointRepository.ViewJoint().ToList()) { AllowNew = true };
```

But when i want to bind just one record to datasource i get binding error :

```
 gridControl.DataSource = new Binding<ViewJoint>(_jointRepository.ViewJoint().First()) { AllowNew = true };
```

Why ?

Comment: It probably has to be an `IEnumerable`. You can fetch the single record and then bind a single element array with it to `DataSource`.

Comment: @TomášHübelbauer The function _jointRepository.ViewJoint() returms  Ienumerable items

Comment: But `First()` doesn't, you need to take what `First` returns an what that in an array.

Comment: @TomášHübelbauer The first returns  a ViewJoint row just it

Comment: You said `ViewJoint` returns `IEnumerable.` Does `ViewJoint().First()` also return `IEnumerable`? I don't understand your last comment. See my answer for what I mean.

Comment: It will also help if you edit the question to include the actual binding error you are getting.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the result of `Single` in an array, so it remains an `IEnumerable`:

```
var single = _jointRepository.ViewJoint().First();
var array = new[] { single };
gridControl.DataSource = new Binding<ViewJoint>(array) { AllowNew = true };
```

Since you specify `AllowNew` you may also need to use a `List`, not an array so adding new items works. The new items will be added to the list, so you need to check it later for new items and save/process them accordingly.

Comment: Can you update the original question with the error message you are getting? And explain what *It doesn't work* means? It doesn't tell me anything.